# palindrome c program is not working for some reason

Tags: c

this program checks weather the entered string is palindrome or not . it should be in a way like it should even tell the string is palindrome if there is space or any special character

like messi is a palindrome of iss em

and ronald!o is a palindrome of odlanor

this is the program and for some odd reason it is strucking and not working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

  char palstr[100], ans[100];

  printf("enter the string for checking weather the string is a palindrome or not");

  scanf("%[^/n]", &palstr);

  int ispalin = 1, i = 0, n = 0;

  int num = strlen(palstr);

  printf("the total length of the string is %d", num);
  while (i <= num) {
    if (palstr[i] == ' ' || palstr[i] == ',' || palstr[i] == '.' ||
        palstr[i] == '!' || palstr[i] == '?') {
      i++;
    }
    palstr[n++] == palstr[i++];
  }

  int j = num;

  i = 0;
  while (i <= num) {
    ans[j--] = palstr[i];
  }
  printf("the reverse of the string %s is %s", palstr, ans);

  if (ans == palstr)
    printf("the string is a palindrome");
  else
    printf("the string is not a palindrome");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program is stucking because `i` is not updated in the `while (i<=num)` loop. There are some more mistakes in your program.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Oh, another mistake is added by editing...

Comment: Tip: Use `for` instead of `while` for fixed-length loops.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: This will be useful: [isalpha(3): char classification routines - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha)

Comment: thankyou everyone. i am really new to stack overflow and programming.

Comment: What on earth is `scanf("%[^/n]", &palstr);`

Answer (score 3):

A few points to consider. First, regarding the code:

```c
if (ans == palstr)
```

This is *not* how you compare strings in C, it compares the *addresses* of the strings, which are always different in this case.

The correct way to compare strings is:

```c
if (strcmp(ans, palstr) == 0)
```

---

Second, you should work out the length of the string *after* you have removed all unwanted characters since that's the length you'll be working with. By that I mean something like:

```c
char *src = palstr, dst = palstr;

while (*src != '\0') {
    if (*c != ' ' && *src != ',' && *src != '.' && *src != '!' && *src != '?') {
        *dst++ = *src;
    }
    src++;
}
```

---

Third, you have a bug in your `while` loop anyway in that, if you get two consecutive bad characters, you will only remove the first (since your `if` does that then blindly copies the next character regardless).

---

Fourth, you may want to consider just stripping out all non-alpha characters rather than that small selection:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
if (! isalpha(*src) {
    *dst++ = *src;
}
```

---

Fifth and finally, you don't really *need* to create a new string to check for a palindrome (though you may still need to if you want to print the string in reverse), you can just start at both ends and move inward, something like:

```c
char *left = &palstr, right = palstr + strlen(palstr) - 1, ispalin = 1;
while (left < right) {
    if (*left++ != *right--) {
        ispalin = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

---

There may be other things I've missed but that should be enough to start on.

Comment: hey , i did that. but still i have no luck. i think there are a lot of mistakes. thankyou for your time\

Comment: @GratusRichard: I've made a more exhaustive list of the things you should look into.

Comment: Maybe look into the `scanf` as well

Answer (score 0):

well, the are so many bugs in this code. I will point them out with comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

        char palstr[100], ans[100];

        printf("enter the string for checking weather the string is a palindrome or not\n");

        scanf("%s", palstr); // your former code won't stop input util Ctrl+D

        int ispalin = 1, i = 0, n = 0;

        int num = strlen(palstr);

        printf("the total length of the string is %d\n", num);
        while (i < num) {  // < insted of <=
                if (palstr[i] == ' ' || palstr[i] == ',' || palstr[i] == '.' ||
                                palstr[i] == '!' || palstr[i] == '?') {
                        i++;
                        continue;// without this, marks still in the string
                }
                palstr[n++] = palstr[i++]; //should be =
        }
        palstr[n] = '\0'; //

        num = n; // the length might be changed

        i = 0;
        int j = num-1; // reverse
        while (i < num) { //
                ans[i++] = palstr[j--]; //
        }
        ans[i] = '\0'; //

        printf("the reverse of the string %s is %s\n", palstr, ans);
        //if (ans == palstr) they can never be equal
        if (strcmp(ans, palstr)==0)
                printf("the string is a palindrome\n");
        else
                printf("the string is not a palindrome\n");

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just one quick note on your 'repaired' `scanf`, `%s` will not allow spaces to be entered.

Comment: that's right. so gets might be better, if space is definitely needed.